# How to query wikipedia api for file when page title is different from filename?

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to retrieve Afghanistan's coat of arms image from wikipedia.

What I'm doing so far is:

Retrieve the infobox for Afghanistan [through here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=Afghanistan&rvsection=0&redirects).

and parse the result to extract:

> "image_coat = Coat of arms of Afghanistan.svg"

Normally, I'd continue by [querying the image info here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Coat_of_arms_of_Afghanistan.svg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json), but this link is missing the real image url.

The problem is that, for Afghanistan, the image is actually `"Emblem_of_Afghanistan.svg"` instead of `"Coat_of_arms_of_Afghanistan.svg".`

However, [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCoat_of_arms_of_Afghanistan.svg) correctly displays the file `"Emblem_of_Afghanistan.svg".`

---

So I'm kind of stuck here. If it were only Afghanistan, I could manually correct it, but this issue arises for many files.

Comment: You might get better traction on webapps.stackexchange.com.  This is directly the kind of question people answer there.  SO is for writing code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try posting over there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the real file is `File:Emblem_of_Afghanistan.svg` is because the Commons page [`File:Coat of arms of Afghanistan.svg`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aCoat_of_arms_of_Afghanistan.svg&redirect=no) is a redirect to [`File:Emblem of Afghanistan.svg`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aEmblem_of_Afghanistan.svg). Unfortunately, the `prop=imageinfo` API [doesn't currently handle Commons redirects](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45930).

To work around that, when this happens (which you can recognize by `imagerepository` in the response, but no URL*), you can instead query the Commons API, while also specifying `redirects`: http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Coat_of_arms_of_Afghanistan.svg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json&redirects

* The query you linked to isn't right, it's missing the `File:` prefix. The right query is: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Coat_of_arms_of_Afghanistan.svg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks a lot!